# Why use google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

Okay, a lot of websites (about 50%) use google analytics. The idea is to know some basic information about your users. But I don't understand why the service is used by so many people, considering 3 things:

1) The code takes time to load. Even the async version takes time and the user sees the loading icon, a bad thing making it seem like your code is terrible or you can't pay a good hosting company.

2) It's a well know script and a some people block it.

3) Google (obviously) get's the data too. Now, don't get me wrong, but why give them free data sacrificing your uses privacy?

2 and 3 are not so important. 1 is. Given the above, what's the drawback of making your own analytics script and serving it to the users? What's the great thing google analytics does and you can't do on your own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say two reasons:

A) It gives you a LOT of convenient visualizations and ways to slice the data - stuff that you would have to build independently. Again - if you just want to watch one number, it doesn't matter much, but you usually want a bigger picture and GA has put a lot of work into making most useful stuff easily available and easy to visualize.

B) Service reliability - basically, the first 10 iterations of whatever solution you choose to implement WILL have bugs (as any programmer who has worked on any meaningful projects knows).

Outsourcing your analytics to GA therefore just saves you a metric ton of time that it would take to reimplement everything yourself and get it working reliably.

As for speed issues - you can always disable GA on the few pages where speed is critical... although considering that page is usually the landing page of the app, that might not be too smart of an idea...

However - in the vast majority of cases, the async GA code is not really the bottleneck for your page. You are probably better off optimizing other aspects of your javascript on the landing page, as the "loading" icon is really something most users do not notice.